# ++ pre-fix operator overload is not working with <<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

Bit of a new C++ dev here. I have a class `Rational` used to represent rational numbers and allow the user to perform arithmetic and relational operations on them. I overloaded all the operators and they're all working properly except when I try to combine the `++/--` pre-fix operators (e.g., `--Rational`) or the `+/-` unary operators with the `<<` output operator, as in:

```
Rational num(7, 2); // initializes rational to 7/2 (fraction)
cout << --num; // should change val to 5/2 (decrements by one)
// error: no match for 'operator<<'(operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'Rational')
```

or:

```
Rational num(1, 10);
cout << -num; // should change to -1/10
// error: no match for 'operator<<'(operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'Rational')
```

Which I don't understand why, because I've overloaded all of these operators to return a `Rational` object, and I've overloaded the `<<` operator to accept a `Rational` object as well. Interestingly enough, when I try this:

```
Rational num(5, 3);
cout << num;
```

It works as intended. So can someone tell me what's going on here?

Relevant code for the class:

```
class Rational
{
private:
    // Instance variables declarations
    int numerator, denominator;
public:
    // Constructors declarations
    Rational(int numer_val, int denom_val = 1);
    Rational();

    // Unary operators declarations
    friend Rational operator +(const Rational &num);
    friend Rational operator -(const Rational &num);
    friend Rational operator ++(Rational &num);
    friend Rational operator --(Rational &num);
    // I/O operators
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &outs, Rational &num);
};

// Constructors definitions

Rational::Rational(int numer_val, int denom_val) : numerator(numer_val)
{
   set_denominator(denom_val); // irrelevant
   simplify(); // irrelevant
}
Rational::Rational() : Rational(0) { }

// Unary operators definitions
Rational operator +(const Rational &num)
{
    return Rational(+num.numerator, num.denominator);
}
Rational operator -(const Rational &num)
{
    return Rational(-num.numerator, num.denominator);
}
Rational operator ++(Rational &num)
{
    num.numerator += num.denominator;
    return num;
}
Rational operator --(Rational &num)
{
    num.numerator -= num.denominator;
    return num;
}
// I/O operators
ostream& operator <<(ostream &outs, Rational &num)
{
    outs << to_string(num.numerator) + "/" + to_string(num.denominator);
    return outs;
}
```

Comment: `ostream& operator <<(ostream &outs, Rational &num)` -> `ostream& operator <<(ostream &outs, const Rational &num)`

Comment: It's even worse than you think: Your operator overloads change the semantic meaning of the operators. For example, the prefix increment and decrement operators should return a reference to the modified object, not a copy of the object. This is done by returning a *reference* to the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of your `operator<<` binds to an l-value reference:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream &outs, Rational & num)
                                          // ^
```

But all your operators return r-values. So for example, when you do:

```
cout << -num;
```

you are trying to bind an l-value reference to an r-value, which is not allowed.

You can fix this by changing `operator<<` to accept a const reference:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream &outs, Rational const & num)
                                          // ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I've seen `const Rational &num` preferred. Is there a reason you like your const after the type name?

Comment: @scohe001 Before or after is a matter of personal preference, it makes no semantic difference (for simple cases like this).

Comment: @scohe001 Consistency. I can always put it after, but there are some cases where I can't put it before. e.g. as a ref qualifier on a member function, or as a top level const on a pointer. Look up "east-const vs west-const" :) I'm an east-const person myself :)

Comment: @scohe001 One of the benefits of `T const &` is that you don't need the spiral rule to read it, just start at the right and read to the left.

Comment: Yes, as @NathanOliver points out, the rule then becomes "const applies to whatever's on it's left ..." and the rest can be ignored :) It's also easier to teach.